# VBA Descending sort does the same thing as Ascending sort

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am having problems with sorting dates. Both xlAscending and xlDescending sort from oldest to newest... Am I doing something wrong here? Everywhere I check they all say do do xlDescending yet its still not working.

```
With inv_twcl_ws.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .SetRange Range("A1:H" & ls_twc_count)
    .SortFields.Add Key:=.Columns(6), Order:=xlDescending
    .Apply
End With
```

The data is a copy of 6 columns from one workbook to another. The data copies over fine the problem only is with the sorting of data. It does not matter what option I use it doesnt change the results.

If it helps I am sorting a column that contains dates.

Comment: What type of data are you sorting? Can you give an example?

Comment: Also if you un-sort it first, does running this at least change the order?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I am sorting a column that contains dates. I add a little more detail to my question.

Comment: it might not fix your problem, but I don't think that the `.` preceding `.Columns(6)` is working like you think since your `With` pulls the `Range().Sort`. I will say that i'm not 100% sure on that one but maybe qualifying the whole range again like `inv_twcl_ws.Columns(6)` would help?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 well look at that. Removing `.` from `.Column()` worked... Thank you very much. I have been fighting with this for 2 hours...

Comment: Hahaha hey, i'm just glad to hear it worked then!

Comment: @Mike-SMT careful - if this code is in a standard module all you did was *removing the dot*, then now `Columns(6)` is referring to **whatever worksheet is currently active** - and that may *or may not* be the `inv_twcl_ws` sheet. Expect problems if/when it isn't.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon good to know. I will see if I can rewrite it so it is not relying on the active worksheet.